# How high can a 'sub floor' be raised withh plywood sheets?

Tags: subfloor

Re-tiling the entryway to my home and had to remove the old mud floor that the old tile had been laid on top of.  This lowered my floor by approximately 2" so now assume I need to raise by that much in order to place the new tile.  My question is can I install multiple 1/2" or 3/4" plywood sheets on top of one another to build up my subfloor the additional 2"?

Comment: You could always build a floor joist system to raise the plywood to the desired height. Probably cheaper than layering ply over the entire area.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it's an expensive way to go, usually.  And plywood is an inferior top surface for tiling onto.

If not simply re-doing the "mud" approach (worth considering - works well, may cost less) you could use (top down) 1/2" backer board (set on thinset), 3/4" plywood, and set the plywood on 3/4" strips spaced 6-12" or so apart, rather than two full sheets of 3/4" ply.

Comment: Gypcrete may also be a solution. I would imagine it is cheaper than a few layers of plywood.

Comment: Gypcrete falls under the mantle of what gets lumped here as "mud" (could also include "full mortar bed" method,) e.g. https://www.tcnatile.com/faqs/65-mortar-bed-compressive-strength.html#faq66

Comment: It's not that expensive. And you can just add cement board on top of it using cement board screws. I have done it many times and the floor has lasted a long time.